# Values for which this set is closed: ill posed question?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am stuck on this exercise, and I also willing to ask you if the question is well posed ornot because I cannot figure out the sense.

Be $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a function defined by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 & x \neq 1 \\ b & x = 1\end{cases}$$
where $b\in\mathbb{R}$.

Find all the values of $b$ for which the set $\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2; y \leq x^2\}$ is closed.

What does $f(x)$ has to do with the question about the closedness of the set?

Comment: Perhaps they meant to write $f(x)$ in place of $x^2$?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the original question meant the set $A = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : y \le f(x)\}$. In this case note that a set is closed if and only if every converging sequence is converging to an element inside the set. Thus take some sequence $(x_n,y_n) \subset A$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x',y')$. We will show that $(x',y') \in A \Leftrightarrow b =1$ and thus the answer will be $b=1$. Note that limits preserve weak inequalities and thus: $\lim y_n \le \lim f(x_n)$ so $y' \le \lim f(x_n)$ whoever $\lim f(x_n) = f(x') \Leftrightarrow$ f is continuous (because then we can "push" the limit inside). It is easy to see that only for $b = 1$ f is continuous.